# improve script to format string based on char position

Tags: string, formatting, dataweave

I have an array of numbers like:

```
["5119229", "757218"]
```

and I must output them with a dot after the second position:

```
["51.19229", "75.7218"]
```

I achieved it by this script:

```
payload map ($[0 to 1] ++ "." ++ $[2 to -1])
```

is there a better way to do this using dataweave 2 (and its libraries?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of strings, not numbers.

This is cleaner though not more efficient; there are other questions like: are the string always the same length? If one is too short, what should we do? Etc.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun formatItem(itm: String) = "$(itm[0 to 1]).$(itm[2 to -1])"
---
payload map formatItem($)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. There is no currently support for fixed point numbers in DataWeave and your numbers are not fixed length.